# Can we use the superlative form adjective and another adjective at the same time?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

I would like to ask about the usage of adjective.

Simply, is it OK to put another adjective with noun which has already had the superlative formed adjective.
For example, to make "the most beautiful thin flower", or to make "the most important fixed table."

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: You probably mean *cooperation*. The answer is yes. Such double adjectival phrases are usually separated by a comma, and the superlative applies only to the first.

Comment: Oh, cooperation is right.  
Thank you for your answer, deadrat. 
I didn't know a comma is usually used when the adjectival phrases are used at the same time.  It's much interesting.

Comment: I don't think you should put a comma there. If you mean that of all the fixed tables, this is the most important, then "the most important fixed table" is right.

Comment: Yes, If of all fixed tables, this is the most important, then "the most important fixed table" fits just as well as “the most beautiful thin flower.”

“The most important, fixed table" seems outlandish; it is unlikely the table was most important because it was fixed, or as well as being fixed.

Not because flowers and tables are different things but more because beauty and importance are different concepts, “the most beautiful, thin flower” seems much more acceptable: the flower might very well be most beautiful either because it was thin, or as well as being thin.

Comment: You can't use multiple superlatives together though. There are some conditions where it would be "okay" but basically you cannot do this: "the most greatest beautifully thin flower". You can say, "the most beautifully thin, fluffy, soft, pink flower...". You just cannot pair superlatives, like in the former example, together in that manner.